# Do the Dark Tower novels reference "shine"?

Tags: the-dark-tower

I'm finally watch the movie and they reference Jake having "the shine". Is this link with The Shining explicit in the books, or an attempt in the film to seem clever?

Comment: Nowhere in the books is such a link. It's "Touch" not "Shining" in quite consequent manner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Stephen King has referred to his other stories quite often. And he even put a fictional version of himself in the Dark Tower. King considers The Dark Tower his magnum opus and it references *It*, *The Mist*, *The Shining* and *The Stand*

It's been awhile since I've read these but you can find those "easter eggs" in the Dark Tower

And, Eddie says he saw the Shining at the movies in *The Drawing of the Three*

And

> Jake is important because he has the ability to shine, just like Danny in *The Shining*

Your question is also related to one of my earlier [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35409/how-much-of-kings-journal-was-true/36040#36040):

Comment: I've read all these books and am well aware SK likes to make fun links. But in the movie they directly link Shine with Breaking many times and IIRC that's not accurate. I wonder if this is implied in the books specifically

Comment: *The Dark Tower his magnum opus and it references It, The Mist, The Shining and The Stand*.... There's slight nods be it characters/places/product names etc... in a *lot* of books/short stories. I'd say the other big hitters (in terms of overlap) though are probably Hearts In Atlantis & Salem's Lot.